# SQL Selection Query getting corrupted

Tags: sql, ms-access

Ive come across a very unusual problem (for me at least) and I have no idea how to solve it.

Essentially I made a really simple selection query to search our clients in a table (dbo_t_Person) and return their records. I needed them to be searchable even if we only have an email address, or phone number for some clients on hand. Therefore I wrote the criteria to either ignore a field if no data was entered, or to search similar (via 'Like') if only partial details were entered into any given field. See the SQL below, apologies for how repetitive it is.

This is all well and good, it works perfectly and is fast enough for our uses.

However.

I can run the query as many times as I wish with new data entered and it works fine, but if I close the query and reopen it, the SQL goes haywire and it runs out of memory and crashes access, this is crashing just opening the SQL as well as running it. By haywire I mean that if i manage to luck out and reopen the SQL, lines of SQL are suddenly copied endlessly on the page.

This happens every time I rewrite the SQL from scratch, how the hell do I stop this happening?

Here is the working clean code:

```vb
SELECT dbo_t_Person.PersonID
    ,dbo_t_Person.FullName
    ,dbo_t_Person.Address1
    ,dbo_t_Person.Address2
    ,dbo_t_Person.City
    ,dbo_t_Person.Zip
    ,dbo_t_Person.STATE
    ,dbo_t_Person.Country
    ,dbo_t_Person.Mobile
    ,dbo_t_Person.Phone
    ,dbo_t_Person.Email
FROM dbo_t_Person
WHERE (
        (
            (dbo_t_Person.PersonID) = [Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![OwnerIDEntry]
            OR [Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![OwnerIDEntry] IS NULL
            )
        AND (
            (dbo_t_Person.FullName) LIKE "*" & [Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![NameEntry] & "*"
            OR [Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![NameEntry] IS NULL
            )
        )
```

And so on for the remaining entry fields

However if I can get the SQL back open again it it appears thousands of lines of

```vb
Or [Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![NameEntry] Is Null
```

for all entry fields is endlessly repeated.

Something is making the code copy end on end, how do I stop it?

Comment: Will query open and pull records without filter criteria? I never use dynamic parameterized query. I prefer VBA to build criteria and apply to form or report.

Comment: Yes it does, it works fine. As soon as I add even just one of the criteria, if I close the query and open it again then its just created multiple new duplicate lines. Seems to be related to the handling of the criteria by access. I agree VBA would be a better option but I was hoping a quick simple SQL selection would do the trick.

Comment: Are these tables links to SQLServer? Import records to a local table and test the query. Still has issue?

Comment: Shouldn't Like " * " `be`Like "*"`(no blanks)?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Yes it is without spaces in the real query, that was a typo on here only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an adjusted `WHERE` clause with `NZ()` to handle if controls are empty or not.

```
WHERE dbo_t_Person.PersonID = NZ([Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![OwnerIDEntry], 
                                 dbo_t_Person.PersonID)
  AND dbo_t_Person.FullName = LIKE "*" & NZ([Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![NameEntry],
                                            dbo_t_Person.FullName) & "*"
```

Comment: Thanks, the Nz() function seems to have done exactly what I needed and kept it tidy enough that it does not corrupt, thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad to help and thanks for confirming (OPs seem to disappear on me!).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your criteria to be more efficient and clean, like this:

```
IIF(ISNULL([Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![OwnerIDEntry]),TRUE,PersonID=[Forms]![from MICHAEL TEST WORKING]![OwnerIDEntry])
```

Since you are only dealing with a single table you can also do away with `dbo_t_Person.` from everywhere, like this:

```
SELECT PersonID,FullName,Address1,Address2,City,Zip,STATE,Country,Mobile,Phone,Email
FROM dbo_t_Person
```

Maybe the simplified version of the SQL will stop Access from corrupting it.

Comment: Thanks, a simplified version indeed seems to stop it corrupting.